# How to split a string by variable number of characters in C#

Tags: c#, split

I read data from the serial port and i want to split this data into smaller digits 
example :

```
        String  inputData = "3032592556231055126395692345723465234578235698"

        output : data1 = "30325925562"
                 data2 = "31055126395"
                 data3 = "692345723"
                 data4 = "465234578"
                 data5 = "235"
                 data6 = "698"
```

that exactly what i wand to do.

Comment: Use the [String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).

Comment: How do you know when data1 ends and data2 begins? Are they always the same number of characters?

Comment: @ Oren Melzer : the data repeat its self but with different values

Comment: @dtb i know the Substring method but i am talking about how to split the data into variable size

Comment: if it repeats itself with `Different Values` the question `Oren` is getting at is, will the data always end up in the 6 formatted structures that you have displayed in your question..? if so then use `SubString()` method or if you are clever enough you could create a `enum` with the file structure and work against it that way

Comment: @ DJ KRAZE : the data will always have this size but the values will get changed

Comment: @Abdelrahman Tarief if you don't understand a basic substring method how is it that you are even wanting to code.. OMG everybody wants to be a developer these days.. I suggest reading `MSDN` on how to use the method ..once again there are 1000s of examples located here [Find 100s of C# Code Examples](http://www.google.com)

Comment: if the data will always be the same size then use substring or create your own List<string> with a data structure, there are many ways to accomplish what you are wanting to do.. have a good night..it's `MILLER TIME` here in the Great State of `TEXAS` good luck\

Comment: who said i don't understand Substring method !!! i am asking on the logic of how to split it into variable size , by the way if u don't have a  constructive comment  so i don't appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data1` and `data2` will always hold 11 digits, `data3` and `data4` 9 digits, and so on, maybe using a `System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex` will help you achieve what you want (without using `SubString`)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(\d{11})(\d{11})(\d{9})(\d{9})(\d{3})(\d{3})");
Match match = regex.Match(inputData);

if (match == Match.Empty)
    // Your inputData did not match the Regex, decide what to do here

data1 = match.Groups[1];
data2 = match.Groups[2];
// etc.
```

I'll admit, this is not the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
string part = new string(inputString.Skip(12).Take(12).ToArray());
```

where you can replace 12 with a variable or two

Comment: If the OP doesn't understand the `SubString()` Method I highly doubt that he will understand the Extension Method you have provided.. awesome code by the way..

Comment: @DJKRAZE if he cares to understand or not - his business. I provided him with an easy-to-replicate one line solution. His question was obviously a noob one but that's besides the point